# differential forms on Lie group

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, principal-bundles

I am studying differential geometry with the help of Taubes’s book. But I meet difficulty when read the part about flat connection.

In the chapter about flat connection ，they say that for a trivial principal bundle$P$= $M \times G$,where G a lie group. $\omega=g^{-1}dg$(at the point $g \in G$ )defines a flat connection on $P$, here $dg$ denotes the pullback form via the projection map$\pi:P \rightarrow G$.

But I have no idea how to calculate $g^{-1}dg (v)$,here $v$ the vector field at $g \in G$.

Thanks you for your help!

Comment: As far as I'm aware the notation $g^{-1}dg$ only makes sense for matrix Lie groups. The equivalent "abstract" definition would be $\omega=\pi_2^*\mu$, where $\mu$ is the [Maurer-Cartan form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurer%E2%80%93Cartan_form) on $G$ and $\pi_2:P\to G$ is the canonical projection.

Comment: @Kajelad Thank! I've gone back to check the Taubes book and I find that  he never mention that $G$ should be a martix group in this chapter , I may treat it as a typo and go forward.

Comment: @Kajelad Sorry，I find I cannot check it really the connection for the matrix case.Could you please tell me how does $g^{-1}dg$ act on the tangent vector? thank!

Comment: If you regard $g$ as a map $G\to M_N$, where $M_N$ is the set of $N\times N$ real matrices, then we can identify $\mathfrak{g}$ with a subset of $M_N$, and regard $dg$ as a map $TG\to M_N$. This allows us to regard $g^{-1}dg$ as a map $TG\to\mathfrak{g}$.